# Sample size in Fisher's exact test with larger contingency tables

Tags: contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I'm using Fisher's tests to evaluate contingency tables that are larger than 2x2; because they relate to transitions between behavioural states, they are usually 8x8, 9x9, sizes like that. I am interested in whether the transitions represented in each table vary across all the rows. For each subject there are a many, many contingency tables produced and I am struggling to decide a cutoff for which to include in my analysis with respect to each table's sample size. For example, some tables will have lots of transitions represented (dozens or hundreds) and clearly warrant inclusion, while others are almost all zeros so any assessment would not be very meaningful. It is in the middle where I am uncertain -- where a few rows have ten or more, or maybe there are less than 10 total values in a few or several different rows. I realize the Fisher's test is meant for small sample sizes, but nonetheless I am trying to determine a useful cutoff so that the tables I assess. Or does the test take into account this issue already?

Comment: The big issue is not whether you can carry out a test at very small sample sizes, it's mostly that you have a limited set of available significance levels (e.g. in some cases there will be none $\leq5\%$), and in any case tests at small sample sizes will tend to have very little power, so it's more that there may be little point in such a test.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Because of that, I'm trying to determine a reasonable way to decide where the cut-off is in that respect. I have not been able to find any information related to that, so any insight would be valued.

Comment: Where you place the cut-off is up to your needs / tolerance for inaccuracy in significance level or for low power. We can't tell you how much it matters if you end up doing a test at 3.4% instead of 5% or how much power you want at a given effect size. We can help you work out things like significance level and power if the information is sufficiently specific (specific enough that it can be done at all).